# how to solve Schrödinger equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I would like to solve a complete solutions of the Schrödinger equation for a particle with time & position dependent mass ($m(x,t)$) moving in a potential $V(x,t)$. Any suggestions to solve analytically or numerically for the corresponding eigenvalues?

Comment: Do you have any explicit potential or mass equation in mind....? Usually the schrodinger equation is hard to solve even knowing what the potential is

Comment: @TylerHG, for example for V(x,t)=A(x)B(t)

Comment: Again, it is not possible to solve like that. We can separate the SE equation in this case and write down two odes but we cant write a solution down

Comment: @TylerHG, there is possible solution for a particle with time-dependent mass moving in time-dependent linear potential by performing a unitary transformation like $\Psi(x,t)=\Phi(x,t)e^{i \beta(t)}$ with $\beta(t)$ being a time-dependent variable.

Comment: and perform the time and space transformation of $y=x+\nu(t)$ and $s=\int_{0}^{\infty}d\sigma/M(\sigma)$

Comment: You said nothing about the potential being linear

Comment: @ TylerHG sorry I forgot to state the potential is linear.